# Bootstrap 3 Pagination - Não centraliza

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

O código abaixo até exagerei nas classes de alinhamento centralizado, e mesmo assim não centraliza (Twitter-Bootstrap 3.7):

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 center-block text-center">
            <nav aria-label="Paginação">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pagination-centered center-block text-center">
                    <li class='active'><a href="?pg=<?php echo $dry*$st; ?>"><?php echo $dry*$st; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="?pg=<?php echo $dry*$st; ?>"><?php echo $dry*$st; ?></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

É porque vc colocou a classe `center-block` no pai e no filho, basta colocar na `col` pai

O display original do `pagination` é `display: inline-block;`, mas quando vc coloca nele `center-block` ele passa a ser `display:block`, e fica ocupando 100% da largura do pai, por isso não centraliza, pois ele está ocupando todo o espaço e não apenas o espaço "dele mesmo"

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


      <section>
         <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 center-block text-center">
                     <nav aria-label="Paginação">
                           <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pagination-centered  text-center">
                              <li class='active'><a href="?pg=<?php echo $dry*$st; ?>"><?php echo $dry*$st; ?></a></li>
                              <li><a href="?pg=<?php echo $dry*$st; ?>"><?php echo $dry*$st; ?></a></li>
                           </ul>
                     </nav>
                  </div>
               </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado Hugo!

Comment: entendi, inspecionei os elementos da nav e entendi melhor, creio que não erro mais com isso =)